# Gallery view Images zoom in and out in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm new one for android development. I developed one gallery application its working fine, but i need to zoom in and out and pan the visible image view. i searched long time in web site but i could not get any result. so any one done this problem please share with me soon.

Thanks in advance